# Undefining a symbol macro

Tags: common-lisp

Is it possible to undefine a symbol macro? It is possible to undefine regular variables, macros and functions using f/makunbound, but I can't seem to find a way to remove symbol macros.

I thought about removing the package they reside in altogether, but that seems like a questionable solution given the CLHS says this about [symbols in deleted packages](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_del_pk.htm):

> After this operation completes, the home package of any symbol whose
> home package had previously been package is implementation-dependent.
> Except for this, symbols accessible in package are not modified in any
> other way; symbols whose home package is not package remain unchanged.

So even if it works it's really just going to re-home them to some implementation dependent location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your best (*portable* and *reliable*) bet is [`unintern`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_uninte.htm):

```lisp
(defvar *things* (list 'alpha 'beta 'gamma))
(define-symbol-macro thing1 (first *things*))
thing1
; ==> ALPHA
(unintern 'thing1)
thing1
; ==> The variable THING1 is unbound.
```

Note that this will also lose the function binding, properties &c.

Another way is to notice that [`define-symbol-macro`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defi_1.htm) "conflicts" with [`defvar`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm):
`(defvar thing1)` will remove the global symbol macro definition from `thing1`.

Note that it will do so silently in SBCL and via a continuable error in CLISP (for symmetry with the opposite order):

```
(defvar thing1)
(define-symbol-macro thing1 (first *things*))
; ==> PROGRAM-ERROR
```

I don't know what happens in other implementations.